# What's the Julia way of creating an empty object with a parameterized type?

Tags: julia

Suppose, we have the following data structure

```
struct MyStruct{T}
    t :: Union{Nothing, T}
end
```

and we want to allow the user to initialize the struct without adding any data such as `MyStruct{T}()`.

So far, I've tried

```
MyStruct() where {T} = MyStruct{T}(nothing)
```

which I try to instantiate with

```
x = MyStruct{Int}()
```

which tells me

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching MyStruct{Int64}()
Closest candidates are:
  MyStruct{T}(::Any) where T at REPL[1]:2
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ REPL[4]:1
```

What's the idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: You wrote "initialize". Attention that if you want later modify your instantiated objects you need yous structure defined as `mutable struct MyStruct{T}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
julia> MyStruct{T}() where T = MyStruct{T}(nothing)

julia> MyStruct{Int}()
MyStruct{Int64}(nothing)
```